# how to make textboxes retain data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access-2013

Okay, so I am trying to make a form with 3 textboxes and next and back buttons. I am supposed to enter data in those textboxes. What I want to do is if I click on the next button, that same form will show its initial state (3 empty textboxes and two button) but if I click on the back button, it will show the data I entered in the textboxes where I entered them. Basically, I want the textboxes be able to retain data. I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I have searched around the net to no avail. Does this require a database or something? Please help :(

Comment: simply like any way to save data on computing save the data to a file or save the data to a database or save data to a variable if you only need it a runtime. please also take time read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You tagged this with an access tag so I guess you already know you want to save it to an access DB.  So what is the question?

Comment: Without any further info given:

Create a "page 1" class and declare it globally on the form. Whenever that page is loaded, the textboxes derive the info from that class, and whenever a user changes the contents of the textbox, change the correpsonding parameter in that class. So if page 1 has three textboxes, the Page 1 class consists of three string variables.

Comment: In fact, you could just declare three strings globally. The key is to use the load and textbox_changed events so that you can change & display the data in these variables.

Comment: @Plutonix has been a little harsh to me since I started asking questions here lol

Comment: On a serious  note, @Ross I believe I will need to create class like you said. I know how to make classes, I just don't know where to start with this one :(

Comment: When you click the Back button, exactly how far back do you need to go? Do you only need the most recently entered text, or do you want to go back further than that if the button is clicked multiple times? Just using a single variable or tag for each TextBox will work as others have suggested if it's the former, but if it's the latter then you could track multiple entries using [`List(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and incrementing/decrementing an index on each button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just create a tag for each textbox containing the text that was in that textbox before you clear the textbox.

```
Textbox1.Tag = Textbox1.Text
Textbox1.Clear()
```

And then to recall with your back button:

```
Textbox1.Text = Cstr(Textbox1.Tag)
```

And once you are done with the data:

```
Textbox1.Tag = Nothing
```

Comment: This kind of works for me, will just do a little tweaking, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a string array. Not sure how familiar you are with vb or coding in general, but an array is just a normal variable that holds a bunch of different information of the same type. (i.e. if you have 3 strings "cat", "dog", and "fish", you can set the array of strings to be strAnimal(2) = {"cat", "dog", "fish"} because vb is quirky and starts at index 0 or simply make it strAnimal() so the number of strings it can hold is nearly limitless)

The way I would do it is this:

```
'all static variables maintain their values even when the click procedure ends
'for ease I am assuming there are values in the arrays already

Static intCounter As Integer   'for index
Const intArrayLimit As Integer = 'whatever you decide you want the most to be stored is

Private Sub btnBack_Click(autocode that Visual Studio puts in for the buttonclick procedures) Handles btnBack.Click

    Static strEntered1(intArrayLimit) As String    'textbox 1 array
    Static strEntered2(intArrayLimit) As String    'textbox 2 array
    Static strEntered3(intArrayLimit) As String    'textbox 3 array

    'decrease counter to previous index
    intCounter = intCounter - 1

    'display stored values
    Me.TextBox1.Text = strEntered1(intCounter)
    Me.TextBox2.Text = strEntered2(intCounter)
    Me.TextBox3.Text = strEntered3(intCounter)

    'disable back button if there are no values before these
    If intCounter = 0 Then
        Me.btnBack.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.btnBack.Enabled = True
    End If

    'enable forward button if there are more values entered beyond those displayed
    If intCounter < intArrayLimit Then
        Me.btnNext.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.btnNext.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Then for the Forward/Next button you add 1 to the counter instead of subtract and I would include a check for values at that index in the array to allow the user to enter values into the textboxes.